# C detect empty line

Tags: c

I have a text file that i need to read and store in struct. It looks something like this:

```
Firstname Lastname
123
345
678

Firstname2 Lastname2
432
454
```

The amount of data that comes after the number part is unknown there may be one line or two or so on. There is always a space when a new person and its data starts. How can I detect when there is an empty line so I can move to the next location in my struct array where I store the data.
When using fgets()

```
buffer[0] == '\n'
```

worked on windows, but it doesnt work on linux.

Comment: Can you post your code? Currently it is unclear to understand your question. Also, do not just dump your code here. Please post an MCVE.

Comment: “It doesn't work” is not an error description. What exactly happened? What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following after the call of `fgets`

```
buffer[strcspn( buffer, "\r\n" )] = '\0';

if ( buffer[0] == '\0' ) { /* the string is empty */ }
```

A more reliable approach is to trim away all leading white spaces in the line.

For example

```
char *p = buffer;

while ( isspace( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;

if ( *p == '\0' ) { /* the string is empty */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use [`fgets`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fgets.html). The documentation states

> The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by s, until n-1 bytes are read, or a newline is read and transferred to s.

This means, also the "newline indicators" are transferred to the buffer. These "newline indicators" may be `"\n"` or `"\r\n"`, depending on the system you are working on.

Therefore: Also check for `"\r\n"`. One way to do so is to use [`strcmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html) and comparing it to zero (which means "equals"):

```
//Check both end-of-line formats (DOS, Unix)
if(strcmp(buffer, "\n") == 0 || strcmp(buffer,"\r\n") == 0) {
  // Empty line read
} else {
  // Line with text read
}
```

Comment: If the file is opened as a text file, this check is ineffective.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *ptr;
ptr = readline(); //reads a line from file
while(*ptr==' ' || *ptr=='\t' || *ptr=='\n' || *ptr=='\r')
 ptr++;

if(*ptr=='\0')
   then it is empty line.
else
{
    do job
}
```

Comment: Upvote because you reminded me that a memory address can be incremented. You just opened a whole new world for me…

Comment: Though what does it mean when you assign a value to `ptr`, but not `&ptr` or `*ptr`? Does it mean that `ptr` holds the entire line, whereas `*ptr` is simply the first byte in the line?

Comment: ptr points to the read data (entire line). I am not using &ptr, as it is a double pointer and points to address of ptr. You are right, *ptr points to first byte in line.